# System of quadratic equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

> Solve the following system.
> $$\left\{\begin{aligned}
> x^2+4 x y+6 y^2  &= 11 \\
> y^2+3 y z+2 z^2  &=  0 \\
> z^2+4 z x+12 x^2 &=  9
> \end{aligned} .\right.$$

---

I have tried several tricks with this system but I am getting nowhere. Can someone please help me with just an idea?

Comment: Over $\Bbb R$?  Over $\Bbb C$?

Comment: it is not mentioned

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: Have you tried using the second equation to eliminate either $y$ or $z$ and thus reduce the equations to two with two unknowns?

Comment: @DavidQuinn yes but I am getting nowhere

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it's a problem given in the course, unfortunately I don't have more information.

Comment: Which course, exactly?  What subject?  What level?

Comment: @Anamaria the Rodrigo de Azevedo's question is important to determine which tools are expected to be used in the problem. Whether you're looking at a course on real analysis, complex analysis, or maybe doing "basic algebra" from some competition. It's not the same look for solutions in ${\bf C}$ or in ${\bf R}$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo 
the course is called methods and techniques for solving problems, which is part of the master's degree .

Comment: @user1027216 I know it's important, but unfortunately in this matter we are given a list of "randam" problems and the requirement is to get the  solutions.
I'm good at math, but some problems really don't come out for me at all.
This is why i need an ideea and then i  try by myself to solve it.

Comment: @Anamaria Master's degree in what field?  Mathematics? Chemistry?

Comment: Note that $y^2+3yz+2z^2=(y+z)(y+2z).$

Comment: By inspection, $(1,1,-1)$ is a solution

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Mathematics, more specifically advanced mathematics.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you, I will try.

Comment: @AnneBauval  now I have the solution, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is noticing that the second equation can be written as
$$(y+z)(y+2x)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow y=-z \text{ or } y=-2z$$

**Case 1:** If $y=-z$, the system of equation becomes
$$\begin{cases}
x^2-4xz+6z^2=11\\
12x^2+4xz+x^2=9\\
\end{cases}$$

which simplifies to
$$\Rightarrow 13x^2+7z^2=20$$
$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{\sqrt{13(20-7z^2)}}{13}\text{ or } x=-\frac{\sqrt{13(20-7z^2)}}{13}$$

**Case 2:** If $y=-2z$, the system of equation becomes
$$\begin{cases}
x^2-4xz+6z^2=11\\
12x^2+4xz+x^2=9\\
\end{cases}$$
$$\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
x^2-8xz+24z^2=11\\
24x^2+8xz+2x^2=18\\
\end{cases}$$
which simplifies to
$$\Rightarrow 25x^2+26z^2=29$$
$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{\sqrt{29-26z^2}}{5}\text{ or } x=-\frac{\sqrt{29-26z^2}}{5}$$
and you can take it from there.

Comment: Ok, the "trick" was in my 1st comment above. It is still not clear  whether the problem is over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C.$ Anyway, Anamaria, note that you still have some work to do since Sam told you (in each case) an equation *implied* by the system but not *equivalent* to it. As he told you at the end: "you can take it from here". I guess you should find a *finite* set of solutions $(x,y,z).$

Comment: sorry the first case needs fixing, I copy pasted wrong, one second. with this method, you can do it over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$ depending on how you solve the single variable equation of $z$ after replacing $x$.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what methods you are allowed to use, but the task here is to calculate a so called *variety*, that is the set of all points where an Ideal of a multivariate polynomial ring vanishes.

This can be tackled using a *groebner basis* of the same ideal with regards to the lexicographic term order.

Using sage we can quickly calculate this groebner basis like this
https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1jcEKwjAQRO-F_sPSU7rGQKIIgnrvrc1VRBIaSiA2kF6SfL0rxdMb3jC7WtwyL7w-4A5jDGWNH2-C9uvCpsmaxCGm2SVqu-By17fNSPmZERUc4IwZC_GC5SeOICWHsncncpWosJLgUP-TipkoFeZ9c321zUBHtfCzM4GN9GQQS4rOri69rdn8xvovAVcsBQ==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

although we could also do this with some effort by hand. This gives us the basis made from
$$ x + \left(-\frac{199740516965191}{20000267695200}\right) z^{7} + \frac{157285576503190573}{4380058625248800} z^{5} + \left(-\frac{11168712229508887}{336927586557600}\right) z^{3} + \frac{7144738116409}{868542261600} z $$
$$ y + \frac{126612178716625}{50571783823968} z^{7} + \left(-\frac{23070511777829797}{2768805164362248}\right) z^{5} + \frac{64521464738498479}{11075220657448992} z^{3} + \frac{367100796197}{366026196624} z $$
$$ z^{8} + \left(-\frac{2540288788}{602720193}\right) z^{6} + \frac{3279495766}{602720193} z^{4} + \left(-\frac{523604604}{200906731}\right) z^{2} + \frac{76295547}{200906731} $$

Note that due to using the lexicographic term order these polynomials descend in number of variables. So to calculate the common roots you can start with the last polynomial to get all possible solutions for $z$, then for each use the second polynomial to get all corresponding solutions for $y,z$ and then for each of these insert into the first polynomial to get all solutions for $x,y,z$.

Comment: This algebraic geometry explanation is correct but much too complicated (and not useful) for a beginner : visibly the asker hasn't the elementary tools for approaching the problem, and/or hasn't spent enough time on his/her issue. Whereas it should be said that the intersection of 3 second degree surfaces (quadrics) gives necessarily rise in general to $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 8$th degree equations.

Comment: @JeanMarie Guess so, yeah ...

Comment: This said, I think it is interesting for the asker to know that more general approaches exist that will be hopefully met one, two, three years later...